# How to fix "failed to initialize SDL in 'System'" in pyxel

Tags: python, python-3.7, sdl-2, pyxel

I was tried to excecute tutorial code include pyxel import, but there was some error "pyxel error: failed to initialize SDL in 'System'"
Should I install some additional packages?

I'm using **WSL (ubuntu18.04)** and **python 3.7.4**.
I already installed :

- libsdl2-dev
- libsdl2-image-dev
- libssl-dev
- zlib1g-dev
- libbz2-dev
- libreadline-dev
- libsqlite3-dev
- wget
- curl
- llvm
- libncurses5-dev
- libncursesw5-dev
- xz-utils
- tk-dev

```
import pyxel

class app:
    def __init__(self):
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that Microsoft does not support graphical programs on WSL. This [article](https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2018/01/30/hands-on-with-wsl-graphical-apps.aspx) describes how to go about using an X server on Windows to accomplish using GUI applications from WSL.

You should be able to install [Xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) (or another X server program of choice) on Windows, and then from inside Ubuntu use the following commands to install some X applications and test to make sure it works properly.

> sudo apt-get install x11-apps
>
> export DISPLAY=:0
>
> xeyes

You should see the xeyes program pop up in a new window.

Now, all you should have to do is export your display before running the pyxel tutorial code.